# How to get parameters that have been bound by JavaScript's .bind() function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How do I get the parameters that have been bound to a function?

```
function add(x){
  return x + 1
}

var func = add.bind(null, x)
// how do I get the value of `x` from the `func` variable alone?
```

Comment: you've already retrieved the variable, which is now stored in func. it that not what you want?

Comment: The code above is simply an example, the context in which I have the `func` variable I do not have the original parameters

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: You can see it in the console under `[[BoundArgs]]`, but I don't think this is accessible in code.

Comment: Yup, in my context I can see it as `[[Scopes]]`, in the console you can right click and press "copy property path" and it gives the correct path but trying to evaluate it throws an error saying it's undefined... Just out of curiosity, how are you seeing `[[BoundArgs]]` in the console? I'm trying to do it with my example but I can't see anything

Comment: @Rob, you can see it by doing: `console.dir(func)`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot natively, but you can create your own bind-like function with few efforts:

```
function bind(fn, boundThis, ...args) {
  const bound = fn.bind(boundThis, ...args)
  bound.__targetFunction__ = fn;
  bound.__boundThis__ = boundThis;
  bound.__boundArgs__ = args
  return bound;
}
```

You use it like `Function.prototype.bind` but you additionally get access to the bound values and the original function:

```
function addOne(x) {
  return x + 1
}
const two = bind(addOne, null, 1)
console.log(two())  // print 2
console.log(two.__boundArgs__)  // print [1]
```